# unresolved external symbol “std::basic_string”

Tags: c++, visual-c++, maven, std, linkage

I am trying to compile a project with Maven via the Visual C++ compiler and I keep getting linkage errors in regards to the std::basic_string class. I ensured that I include the < string > header file into the corresponding c++ file.

Did I miss something or did I make a silly mistake??? Please let me know where I went wrong.

```
[ERROR] Parsor.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

"__declspec(dllimport) public:
    int __thiscall std::basic_string<
        char,
        struct std::char_traits<char>,
        class std::allocator<char> >::compare(
            class std::basic_string<
                char,
                struct std::char_traits<char>,
                class std::allocator<char> > const &) const"

(__imp_?compare@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEHABV12@@Z)
```

Comment: basic_string is a template, so it should never appear as a symbol.

Comment: the silly mistake - use std::string ... never touch std::basic_string unless you wish to implement your own typedef of basic_string. (i do not recommend doing that.)

Comment: I do not use std::basic_string directly, I only use std::string

Answer (score -3):

It seems that the linker settings might be incorrect in your VC++. Try a simple program to test std::strig functionality

Possible duplicate to:

[unresolved external symbol..no idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928238/unresolved-external-symbol-no-idea)

[Solving “locally defined symbol” and “unresolved external symbol” that originates from the .lib files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757962/solving-locally-defined-symbol-and-unresolved-external-symbol-that-originate)